# AmazonHttpClient adding trailing slash to URL endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, httpclient

I've a post request which has AWS4 Signature authentication. I'm using [AmazonHttpClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/http/AmazonHttpClient.html) which comes from the aws-java-sdk-core dependency.

I'm using the following code to make a POST request to url that ends with '/v2/forms/extract'

```
public Object test() throws URISyntaxException {
    var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            this.accessKey,
            this.secretKey
    );

    var signer = new AWS4Signer();
    signer.setRegionName("us-east-1");
    signer.setServiceName("execute-api");

    var request = new DefaultRequest<>("execute-api");
    request.setEndpoint(new URI(this.baseUrl + "/v2/forms/extract"));
    request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);

    request.addParameter("input", "PDF");
    request.addParameter("latest", "true");
    request.addParameter("sort", "true");
    request.addParameter("output", "CSV");
    request.addParameter("score", "true");

    request.addHeader("x-api-key", this.apiKey);
    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

    signer.sign(request, credentials);

    AmazonHttpClient client = new AmazonHttpClient(new ClientConfiguration());
    Response<AmazonWebServiceResponse<String>> response = client
            .requestExecutionBuilder()
            .request(request)
            .executionContext(new ExecutionContext(false))
            .execute(new StringResponseHandler());

    return response.getAwsResponse().getResult();
}
```

However, in the logs I can see a trailing slash added to the url before the query params, which is causing the request to fail.

How can I prevent the trailing slash from going into the response? (I don't have access to the server side, can't rewrite the api)

```
http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /v2/forms/extract/?input=PDF&latest=true&sort=true&output=CSV&score=true HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: uat-api-****************.net[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue was I added the full url to endpoint

```
request.setEndpoint(new URI(this.baseUrl + "/v2/forms/extract"));
```

`setEndPoint` and `setResourcePath` should be used to form the full url

```
request.setEndpoint(new URI(baseUrl));
request.setResourcePath("/v2/forms/extract");
```